# Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer crash

Tags: visual-studio

Recently i got this error in Solution Explorer while working.
Looked through it already, disabled some GPU's optimization that was mentioned in some guides, but still no result.

Here's the full error

```
Failed to create view with exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetDefaultEvent' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.SolutionExplorer.LocalizableProperties' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethod(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternalCore(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, IntPtr[] typeInstantiationContext, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr[] methodInstantiationContext, Int32 methodInstCount)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveMethodHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 methodToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveMethod(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.Reflection.ResolverExtensions.Resolve(MethodRef methodRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.Reflection.MemberRef.get_MemberInfo()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__11_0(RuntimeImport import)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.AttachedCollectionService.OnCollectionSourceProvidersAdded(Object sender, LazyActivationAddedEventArgs`2 e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.LazyActivationWrapper`2.ScanForNewApplicableComponents(ComponentScanReason scanReason)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.LazyActivationWrapper`2.<<EnsureComponents>b__25_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.LazyActivationWrapper`2.EnsureComponents()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.LazyActivationWrapper`2.GetOrderedApplicableComponents()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.AttachedCollectionService.AggregateItemsSource(Object item, String relationshipName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.AttachedCollectionService.GetOrCreateCollectionSource(Object item, String relationshipName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPane.HookShowSolutionNodeEvents(IVsHierarchyItem solution)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPane.RefillNavigator(Boolean skipRestorePhase, Boolean isFirstLoad)
```

Im tried everything that was mentioned in guides related to this problem, but im still struggling with it. Thank's to everyone in advance :)

Comment: More likely to be caused by corrupted installation. You might have to uninstall VS completely and install again.